# How to use javascript code on content from AJAX without including it everytime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have index.php that the user inputs day, month, year etc, and with ajax I display the results.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchBtn').click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'get_spendings.php',
                        data: {
                            day: $('[name=day]').val(),
                            weekday: $('[name=weekday]').val(),
                            month: $('[name=month]').val(),
                            year: $('[name=year]').val(),
                            perpage: $('[name=perpage]').val()
                        },
                        success: function(result) {
                            $('#content').html(result);

                            $.getScript('js/delete_spending.js');
                            $.getScript('js/edit_spending.js');
                        }
                    });
                });

                $('#searchBtn').trigger('click');
});
```

On get_spendings.php I send the results as a complete html output

This is the code for 1 result

```
echo '<div id="spending' . $row['id'] . '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' .
            '<span id="price' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['price'] . '</span>' .
            '<span id="currency' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['value'] . '</span>: ' .
            '<span id="title' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</span>' .
            '&nbsp;<button class="edit_spending" value="' . $row['id'] . '">e</button>' .
            '&nbsp;<button class="delete_spending" value="' . $row['id'] . '">x</button></div>';
```

this is the delete_spending.js javascript file called by the ajax at the end

```
$('.delete_spending').click(function(e) {
    var s_id = Number($(this).val());
    var s_price = $('#price' + s_id).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'delete_spending.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: s_id,
            price: s_price
        },
        success: function(result) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

            $('#spending' + s_id).fadeOut(300, function() {
                $('#spending' + s_id).remove();
            });

            var date_id = $('#spending' + s_id).parent().closest('div').attr('id');
            var num_spendings = $('#'+date_id).children().length;

            if (num_spendings - 1 <= 1)
                $('#'+date_id).fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $('#'+date_id).remove();
                });

            $('#total_spendings').html(Number(Number($('#total_spendings').text()) - Number(json.old_price)).toFixed(2));
        }
    });
});
```

The problem I have is that these 2 files `$.getScript('js/delete_spending.js'); $.getScript('js/edit_spending.js');` must be loaded on every action that comes from the ajax response html, or else it wont work... and as you can see it gets loaded way to much https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjF4X.jpg

I tried to load it at the end, put it in a script tag at the end of the ready, nothing works, and I', not enough experienced to understand why, maybe it has something to do with the scopes, but I thought javascript just loaded whatever script i have and it finds it everywhere, guess thats not the same with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the reason this is happening is the same reason it would happen for any dynamically added element to the page. Let me go into detail of what seems to be happening here (correct me if I'm wrong).

When you select elements with jQuery, and then add in an event handler, such as `.click(function() {});`, it adds the event handler **to the elements that it has already selected**.

This means that you need to rebind the event handlers for dynamically added elements, because they'll be added without the handlers. Luckily, jQuery has an easy solution, and that's to use

`$(document).on('eventNames', 'selector', function() { // HANDLER FUNCTION //})'`

This is triggered every time the events you list occur, because it's happening in the document, then jQuery goes and finds if it's true for any matching selector, and then the handler happens for each of those elements. In your case you'd want something like this:

`$(document).on('click','.delete_spending', function() { // YOUR FUNCTION // });`

Comment: the issue I'm having with this method, is that on the second click the button will work, maybe because on the first it registers... can this be solved?

Comment: You need to make sure that you put your function in the global script. In your main `<script>` tag, put `$(function() { // EVERYTHING THAT SHOULD HAPPEN WHEN THE PAGE IS DONE LOADING // }` Putting all the handler functions in there makes it so they should always work.

Comment: Wait, did you put the `.click(function() {})` inside the `.on('click')`? The `.click(function() {})` isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: If either of our solutions worked, please accept the answer so that it's not an unanswered question!

Comment: neither worked so far... ill refactor some of it, and try it later

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, the problem is that you need to register the click-function every time you add a spending to the DOM?

In that case you can use the [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It says in the API that the DOM ite doesn't have to exist at the time of binding the selector.

However, I have had problems with it not working correctly all the time. What you can do is create a function that registers it instead of loading a new file all the time:

```
function registerDeleteSpending(){
$('.delete_spending').click(function(e) {
    var s_id = Number($(this).val());
    var s_price = $('#price' + s_id).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'delete_spending.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: s_id,
            price: s_price
        },
        success: function(result) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

            $('#spending' + s_id).fadeOut(300, function() {
                $('#spending' + s_id).remove();
            });

            var date_id = $('#spending' + s_id).parent().closest('div').attr('id');
            var num_spendings = $('#'+date_id).children().length;

            if (num_spendings - 1 <= 1)
                $('#'+date_id).fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $('#'+date_id).remove();
                });

            $('#total_spendings').html(Number(Number($('#total_spendings').text()) - Number(json.old_price)).toFixed(2));
        }
    });
});
}
```